# Triggering Backbone model events don't register in my Jasmine spies

Tags: testing, backbone.js, jasmine

I am trying to test that a view method gets called when my model triggers an event. But this isn't working - and I have run out of ideas why this would be. Here's the code that isn't working:

View:

```
class View extends Backbone.View
  initialize: ->
    @.listenTo @model, 'request', @disableForm, @

  disableForm: ->
    console.log 'disableForm'
```

Jasmine Test:

```
describe "AJAX events", ->

  it "when starting an AJAX request, disable the form", ->
    model = new Backbone.Model()
    view = new Backbone.View( { model: model })
    view.render()

    spyOn(view, 'disableForm')
    view.delegateEvents()

    model.trigger 'request'
    expect(view.disableForm).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

This code works in the browser fine.

Also - the console.log does print 'disableForm' when I run the tests - so the model event is triggering the call to disableForm, but my spy is not picking this up (my expectation fails). I have tried putting it into a waitsFor method, but his too did not make a difference.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `spyOn` will replace the function `disableForm` in your view with a `spy` function. But at this time the model was bound to the original function, so replacing the function in the view has no effect on the function that was bound to the event listener. When you trigger the event on the model the original function will be called and not the spy.

Comment: Ah yes. This makes complete sense. Thank you.

Comment: what is the recommended approach to testing components in a module? I could start and stop module before each test, but that does not mimic the actual behavior

Comment: The way I've had to deal with this is by spying on the prototype methods nice and early in your test. So:

    spyOn(View.prototype, 'disableForm');

This ensures that when your methods are bound, they are bound to a spied version of the method. It's not great, and leads to slightly less well-encapsulated tests, but it works.

Another way would be to change the implementation of the binding to accept a method name rather than a function reference. That way you can call the method by name on each event. But changing the binding implementation is a bit heavy!

Answer (score 0):

Might be a concurrency issue. Rather than using an integration test, it might be easier to unit test the `disableForm` method directly and then test that the `initialize` makes the correct binding (or better yet, use the `Backbone.View.events` hash).

Also, the call to `view.delegrateEvents()` appears to be unnecessary in your test. This is due to the fact that `Backbone` will call `delegateEvents` by default on view instantiation and it only interacts with the `events` hash, which does not appear to be used.

Comment: True - the delegateEvents here actually makes no difference as it just refers to the events hash. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above correctly clarify why this is happening: the function is bound on initialization, the spy replaces the function after binding so the original function is called when the event is triggered.

A solution less cumbersome than replacing the prototype's function on test setup (before initialization) is to bind an anonymous function to the event and call the view's function inside of it.

```
@listenTo(model, event, => @viewFunction())
```

I'm not sure what the performance tradeoffs are though.